# belong_to multiple parents

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Hi I'm new to Elixir and models/DB/APIs in general and I'm a bit lost in how to achieve the following:

I want to create an Event when I do a POST in my API to `/v1/events` sending both `tag_id` and `gate_id` but I don't know how to handle this in my controller.

I've done this with simpler models where they just `belong_to` one parent and I just pipe the `build_assoc` in the `changeset`, however, I'm lost on how to do it with multiple parents. I even tried a sketchy solution to manually create a changeset manually setting the `gate_id` and `tag_id` like this `Event.changeset(%Event{"gate_id" => gate_id, "tag_id" => tag_id}, event_params)` however it errored out saying `gate_id` and `tag_id` are not part of the model.

So two questions:
What is the correct way to handle this situation? Am I even close or my models are wrong?

Also does a POST to `/v1/events` passing both of the ids sounds good or am I also lost in that one?

**Models for reference**

Tag model:

```
defmodule Tracker.Tag do
  use Tracker.Web, :model

  schema "tags" do
    field :epc, :string
    field :name, :string
    field :is_active, :boolean, default: false
    field :is_inside, :boolean, default: false

    has_many :events, Tracker.Event

    timestamps
  end

 @required_fields ~w(epc name is_active is_inside)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
    |> cast_assoc(:events, required: false)
  end
end
```

Gate Model:

```
defmodule Tracker.Gate do
  use Tracker.Web, :model

  schema "gates" do
    field :name, :string
    field :direction_in, :boolean, default: false
    field :antenna, :integer
    belongs_to :reader, Tracker.Reader

    has_many :events, Tracker.Event

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(name direction_in antenna)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
    |> cast_assoc(:events, required: false)
  end
end
```

**Update: More info**

Event Model:

```
defmodule Tracker.Event do
  use Tracker.Web, :model

  schema "events" do
    belongs_to :tag, Tracker.Tag
    belongs_to :gate, Tracker.Gate

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w()
  @optional_fields ~w()

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end
end
```

Events Migration:

```
defmodule Tracker.Repo.Migrations.CreateV1.Event do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:events) do
      add :tag_id, references(:tags, on_delete: :nothing)
      add :gate_id, references(:gates, on_delete: :nothing)

      timestamps
    end
    create index(:events, [:tag_id])
    create index(:events, [:gate_id])

  end
end
```

Event controller create function (kind of lost on this one)

```
  def create(conn, %{"event" => event_params}) do
    gate_id = conn.assigns.gate_id
    tag_id = conn.assigns.tag_id

    changeset = Event.changeset(%Event{"gate_id" => gate_id, "tag_id" => tag_id}, event_params)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, event} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:created)
        |> put_resp_header("location", v1_event_path(conn, :show, event))
        |> render("show.json", event: event)
      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        |> render(Tracker.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

And the latest error I'm getting is

```
== Compilation error on file web/controllers/v1/event_controller.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/controllers/v1/event_controller.ex:22: unknown key "gate_id" for struct Tracker.Event
```

Comment: Try changing `%Event{"gate_id" => gate_id, "tag_id" => tag_id}` to `%Event{gate_id: gate_id, tag_id: tag_id}` to fix the latest error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post your error and your migration for `Event` as well? I believe you need to add `tag_id` and `gate_id` to required fields in your model:

```
defmodule Tracker.Event do
  use Tracker.Web, :model

  schema "events" do
    belongs_to :tag, Tracker.Tag
    belongs_to :gate, Tracker.Gate

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(tag_id gate_id)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end
end
```

Comment: Added the required_fields and updated my question with the files you suggested and the current error.

Comment: Thank you guys, a combination of this to ensure tag_id and gate_id were always there and @Dogbert's comment to fix my current syntax problem solved my issues.

Comment: @user1364649 note that adding `tag_id` and `gate_id` to `@required_fields` will allow users to set those fields themselves to arbitrary value. I don't know if you want to disallow that or not seeing as you're fetching them from `conn.assigns` by default.

Comment: @Dogbert Interesting, I'm a bit confused. So before adding this I had `@required_fields ~()`, which means all the fields are required by default, so why did I had to add them? Is it because they are not really fields in my model?

You are correct, I'm letting the user pass the `tag_id` and `gate_id` and rely on the DB constraints. Is this a normal approach?